# How to type assert with switch using reflect.Type

Tags: go, struct, types

I'm using the [structs](https://godoc.org/github.com/fatih/structs#Field.Kind) library to iterate easily over the fields of a struct, e.g:

```
package main

import "github.com/fatih/structs"

type T struct {
}

func main() {
  s := structs.New(T{})
  for _, field := range s.Fields() {
    switch field.Kind() {
    case bool:
      // do something
    case string:
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Current the code above doesn't work because of field.Kind is a reflect.Type. Is it possible to make it work somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see that the `Kind()` method returns a `reflect.Kind`, which is one of the following:

```
type Kind uint

const (
    Invalid Kind = iota
    Bool
    Int
    Int8
    Int16
    Int32
    Int64
    Uint
    Uint8
    Uint16
    Uint32
    Uint64
    Uintptr
    Float32
    Float64
    Complex64
    Complex128
    Array
    Chan
    Func
    Interface
    Map
    Ptr
    Slice
    String
    Struct
    UnsafePointer
)
```

So you'll need the cases to be like `reflect.Bool` instead of simply `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Use predefined reflect kind constants:

```
for _, field := range s.Fields() {
    switch field.Kind() {
    case reflect.Bool:
      // do something
    case reflect.String:
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```